# method type parameter of type[A: Read : Write]

Tags: scala

in the method definition below

```
def fixed[A: Read : Write](start: Int, end: Int, align: Alignment = Alignment.Left,
                             padding: Char = ' ', defaultValue: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]): Codec[A]
```

what does `[A: Read : Write]` mean

Comment: I would be more worried about having `null` as a default value for an argument...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *[Context Bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html)* introduced in **Scala 2.8**, which is a shorthand for providing **implicit arguments**. In your case, it means that, `Read[A]` and `Write[A]` values are implicitly provided.

Traditionally, you may provide implicit arguments for **Read** and **Write** for type **A** as:

```
def fixed[A](some params...)(implicit read: Read[A], write: Write[A]) = ???
```

But, same can be done using context bound as below. However, you have to use `implicitly` in order to access implicit value:

```
def fixed[A : Read : Write](some params...) = {
    val read = implicitly[Read[A]]
    val write = implicitly[Write[A]]
    ...
}
```